# Initialization of several connections to each query

Tags: mysql, node.js

I tried to create a DB class to persist my connection.
The problem is that with each request, it initializes a new connection and after a while I receive this error:

> Error: Packets out of order. Got: 1 Expected: 0

So I tried to destroy my connection after each query, but it doesn't work.

Here is my class:

```js
import mysql from 'mysql';

export default class CMysql {
    constructor() {
        this._mysql = mysql;
        this._host = 'localhost';
        this._port = 3306;
        this._user = 'root';
        this._password = '';
        this._dbName = 'gmdb';
    }

    #Connection = () => {
        return this._mysql.createConnection({
            host: this._host,
            port: this._port,
            user: this._user,
            password: this._password,
            database: this._dbName
        });
    }

    Query = (q, args, cb) => {
        this.#Connection().query(q, args, cb);
        this.#Connection().destroy();
    };
}
```

I guess I'm doing it wrong, but I can't find the logic to have.

Comment: Why multiple connections?

Comment: I don't know what went through my head yesterday, but indeed I didn't understand that I returned a new connection with each query

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I returned with each query a new connection.
I went through the `createPool` method also to limit connections.

My problem is therefore solved.